# Jupyter notebook - can't install

Tags: python, jupyter

```
pip install jupyterlab --user   

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/xxx/Library/Python/2.7'
Check the permissions.
```

Doesn't work.

So I tried

```
pip install --user jupyter
```

Same error:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/xxx/Library/Python/2.7'
```

And so I tried

```
pip install jupyterlab
```

Same error!!

Any idea what might be causing this? It's infuriating! :( help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
sudo pip install jupyterlab
```

Comment: I was under the impression install with sudo was bad?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to install Jupyter to be used with the default python installation in your system (I mean, you're not using Anaconda for example) So, I think the files you want to install must be copy in a system folder wich are accesibles only by superuser (sudo) by default, so you need sudo to make this operation.

Comment: @amlarraz There's no need to preface pip with `sudo` for that purpose. A symbolic link can be used instead.

Comment: @karel I never did that however I think is a really clever fix for this problem to avoid sudo. However,  will you  need sudo to create the symbolic link?

Comment: Yes, if the symbolic link is located in a directory that the user needs root permissions in order to create a file in it.

Comment: weird, I dont get why I dont have permission. It's my machine!

Comment: This is because when you use your Linux (or Mac) machine, your user is only a normal user (even if is your machine) and the system blocks your access to the system files to avoid problems (like accidentally remove or modify system file). If you want to modify anything in the system files you must be superuser (sudo). You can think in this like a double-check you must to do before modify anything in the system.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try installing [JupyterLab](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) using [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html)?

**Install miniconda**

- `wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.5.4-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg`
- Install the above-downloaded pkg to the default location (/miniconda3)
- Add miniconda to path `export PATH="/miniconda3/bin:/miniconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/.bin:$PATH"`

**Create Conda Env and Install JupyterLab**

- `source ~/.bash_profile`
- `conda create -n jlab python=3.6.8 jupyterlab`
- `conda activate jlab`
- `conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab=2`

**Start the server**

- `jupyter lab`